# tkinter option menu doesn't display selection

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, optionmenu

I have a python/tkinter program using option menues that works fine, however in the second window (a window that the main window opens and is a seperate tk execution)  the option selected doesn't appear in the optionmenu. i've tested and the option is selected and I can use it, it just doesn't display.

The following class is called by the main window:

```
class ftp_window:
    def __init__(self):
        root = Tk()
        root.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)
        root.title("Unity Acesso ao FTP")
        root.iconbitmap("icon.ico")
        note = Notebook(root)
        self.tab1 = Frame(note)
        self.tab2 = Frame(note)
        note.add(self.tab1, text = "Acessar Bases")
        note.add(self.tab2, text = "ANALISE")
        root.minsize(600,500)
        root.geometry("600x500")
        self.ftp_apelido = StringVar()
        self.ftp_apelido.set("Select")
        self.varvoz = StringVar()
        self.tab_one()
        note.pack()
        root.mainloop()

    def get_list_of_apelidos(self):
        '''sqlite3 connection for ftp connections'''
        conn = sqlite3.connect("settings.db")
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("select * from ftp_server_login")
        results = c.fetchall()
        list = ()
        for line in results:
            if not re.search(line[4], str(list)):
                list += (line[4],)
            else:
                pass
        return list


    def prints(self, *args):
        '''used to display the stringvar when selected.'''  
        print args
        print self.ftp_apelido.get()


    def tab_one(self):
        '''creates the first tab and it's widgets'''
        main_tab_one_frame = Frame(self.tab1)
        main_tab_one_frame.config(width=300)
        main_tab_one_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=NSEW, rowspan=10, columnspan=10)
        apelidos_Entry = OptionMenu(main_tab_one_frame, self.ftp_apelido, self.ftp_apelido.get(),  *self.get_list_of_apelidos())
        apelidos_Entry.config(width=25)
        apelidos_Entry.grid(column=3, row=3)
        vozEntry=OptionMenu(main_tab_one_frame, self.varvoz, '', '', 'SIM', 'NAO')
        vozEntry.config(width=15)
        vozEntry.grid(column=1, row=4)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating more than one instance of `Tk`, that's at least part of the problem. You should only ever create a single instance of `Tk` for your entire app, and you should only ever call `mainloop` exactly once. If you need more windows you should create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: You are the true and only in a room full of geniuses. That solved perfectly my questio.  muito obrigado. :)